# Postgres upgrade issue from 9.3 to 9.4

Tags: postgresql

I upgraded Postgres from 9.3 to 9.4. But when I login to server then it is showing 9.3.

see the screenshot details below:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.10
$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.4.10
```

```
$psql
psql (9.4.10, server 9.3.13)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select version();
                                                           version                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 9.3.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4, 64-bit
        (1 row)
```

How can I upgrade it? What is the issue?

**Updated:** 
After running pg_lsclusters, it is showing:

```
pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.3 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
```

Comment: How did you upgrade ? Please write your steps to find where the mistake is. You may want to check [Upgrading a PostgreSQL Cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/upgrading.html) or [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgupgrade.html)

Comment: Try the magic pg_lsclusters command, it will show you if you have 2 running instance (or more), you may still connect on the 9.3 if you don't specify the right port.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't upgrade the database. You're likely on a system that permits different versions of PostgreSQL to run concurrently and you likely have two versions of the server running on two different ports. Usually `5432..543x`. You'll have to

1. use `pg_dump` on the server running with the old port (the one you're connecting to here).
2. use `pg_restore` on the server running with the new port (that you probably didn't even know was running)

Try

```
sudo rgrep -i "port =" /etc/postgresql
```

Or, if you have Debian/Ubuntu, run `pg_lsclusters`